# HTTP Web Service call using C language

Tags: c, web-services, http

Which are libraries available to get the URL response using C/C++ language?
At present I am searching for GSOAP library for C/C++ but can not find proper solution.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450488/a-good-c-library-for-soap

Answer (score 0):

If you are just going to retrieve a URL response, the curl lib will do the job.  If you are specifically dealing with SOAP, then another library will be necessary to parse the response (or a standalone library may be used to do the retrieval + response parsing all at once).

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS development, but the library will  probably need to be built for that target platform.  I have not tested, but the following site advertises scripts and binaries for common libraries including curl: [ios-static-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/ios-static-libraries/).